# Error Handling in apex class method.

Tags: apex, error-messages, form

I have an apex method that requires three fields, an account number, user input and custom setting number. based on that it will generate a sequence of number
e.g if the acccount no is 8181818 (OpenReach) userinput is 3 and the custom setting number is 1112 . it will generate 
1113 Openreach 
1114 OpenReach 
1115 OpenReach

But it the account number doesn't correspond with an account it will come up with

1113 
1114 
1115

I already put an required field on the form that handles an empty field. But I can't figure out how to display an error message so that it shows and stops the code from going any further. 
 
Here is what I tried to do:

```
public void genumber(){

         List<Account> lstAccount = [Select Name, Customer_Account_Number__c 
         from Account where Customer_Account_Number__c =:uano limit 1];


    if(lstAccount.size() > 0){
         AccName = lstAccount[0].Name;
    } else { ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'The account number is invalid')); }


         mapUserInputToLargeNo = new map<Integer, Decimal>();
         do{


        if(cslist.size() >0)
        largeNum = cslist[0].Largest_Number__c;
        largeNum ++;

        for (Number_Setting__c updt : cslist){
            updt.Largest_Number__c = largeNum; 
            update updt; 

        }  

         mapUserInputToLargeNo.put(userinput, largeNum);
         userinput --;

      } while(userinput >  0);
   }
```

I've also tried to do the error handling and do it other way around:

```
      if (lstAccount.IsEmpty()) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'The account number is invalid'));
         system.debug('no accounts found');
     }
        else{system.debug('Found account name ');}
```

Has anyone got any idea ? I want a red error message popping out "Account doesn't exist" and stop the execution.

Comment: You should add a `<apex:messages/>` tag to the visualforce page. It will display all `ApexPages...` messages on the page.

Comment: But it will still generate the numbers without the account name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a message on your page you can add `<apex:messages/>` as suggested in the comments.
And to stop execution you need to put the code that you don't want to execute if Account was not found inside your `if(lstAccount.size() > 0){ ... }` block. You can also add a `return` statement like that:

```
if(lstAccount.size() > 0){
     AccName = lstAccount[0].Name;
} else { 
     ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'The account number is invalid'));  
     return;
}
```

That will stop your method execution after the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to add code for a couple other possible errors:

1. The SOQL query may throw an exception if `uano` doesn't match an Account
2. Largest_Number__c may be null, which will throw an exception
3. `update updt;` may throw a limit exception if `cslist` is large. In general, avoid doing DML in a loop.

There are a few non-exception issues as well: confusing indentation, naming conventions, method complexity... These won't errors now, but make readability and maintainability difficult, which may cause bugs down the road.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/188530)